# What are areas off a highway?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning, expressions

I've found the following passage a few days ago when I happened to read a report in DAWN, a Pakistani newspaper.

> The queries sought information about title to and acreage of the land being sold as Bahria Town Karachi, development of BTK infrastructure being financed by MDA and allegations of inexpensive land from distant dehs being consolidated on prime areas off Super Highway for Bahria.

Here's the link to the article.

[Bahria Town Karachi: Greed unlimited](https://www.dawn.com/news/1252809)

Now my question is, what is meant by the phrase "areas off Super Highway"?

Super Highway is the main road that connects Karachi to the rest of the Sindh province to the north.

I've always struggled with the usage of the word "off" as in the above passage. So I would appreciate a number of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster,

> [off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off)
>   1 a — used as a function word to indicate physical separation or distance from a position of rest, attachment, or union • take it *off* the table • a path *off* the main walk • a shop just *off* the main street

These areas are near the Super Highway. The usage of *off* suggests that they are close to the Super Highway, such that when you exit the highway, you've arrived at those areas. You don't have to travel very far once you've exited the highway to reach them.